# node.js opc ua many monitored items

Tags: javascript, node.js, opc-ua, node-opcua

I use `node-opcua module` and
I would like to monitor many `opc ua nodes` with subscription 
I see result like: user in html UI choose what nodes to monitor, then click Monitor button that sent these `nodeIds` as parameters and then for every `nodeid` will be set subscription and .on("changed") works for every of these items like in parallel. Now code looks like:

```
 var monitoredItem  = the_subscription.monitor({
       nodeId: opcua.resolveNodeId("ns=6;s=S71500ET200MP station_1.Master.111"),
       attributeId: 13
   },
   {
       samplingInterval: 100,
       discardOldest: true,
       queueSize: 10
   },
   opcua.read_service.TimestampsToReturn.Both
   );
   console.log("-------------------------------------");
   var nodes = [];

   monitoredItem.on("changed",function(dataValue){
      //console.log(" value = ",dataValue.value.value);
      //console.log(" sourceTimestamp = ",dataValue.sourceTimestamp.toISOString());
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(dataValue));
      var Node = {nodeId: "ns=6;s=S71500ET200MP station_1.Master.111", nodeName: "111" , nodeValue: dataValue.value.value , nodeTimestamp: dataValue.sourceTimestamp.toISOString()};
      var arrayNode = Object.keys(Node).map(function(k) { return Node[k] });
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(Node));
      nodes.push(arrayNode);

    //  console.log(nodes);
   });
},
```

Right now if I want to set new item to monitor it just add many vars MonitorItem1 , ..2 , ..3 etc.

How to do it in more `agile/dynamic` way? if I have array(strings) of `nodeIds` and I want each of these to be monitored in subscription. 
Code is part of `async.series`([ code ])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved using async.each method

```
async.each(nodeIdArr, function(nodeid, callback) {

     var monitoredItem  = the_subscription.monitor({
           nodeId: opcua.resolveNodeId(nodeid),
           attributeId: 13
       },
       {
           samplingInterval: 100,
           discardOldest: true,
           queueSize: 10
       },
       opcua.read_service.TimestampsToReturn.Both
       );
       console.log("-------------------------------------");


       monitoredItem.on("changed",function(dataValue){
          //console.log(" value = ",dataValue.value.value);
          //console.log(" sourceTimestamp = ",dataValue.sourceTimestamp.toISOString());
          //console.log(JSON.stringify(dataValue));
          var Node = {nodeId: nodeid, nodeName: "111" , nodeValue: dataValue.value.value , nodeTimestamp: dataValue.sourceTimestamp.toISOString()};
          var arrayNode = Object.keys(Node).map(function(k) { return Node[k] });
          //console.log(JSON.stringify(Node));
          nodes.push(arrayNode);

        //  console.log(nodes);
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use the method ***the_subscription.[monitorItems()](https://node-opcua.github.io/api_doc/2.32.0/classes/node_opcua.clientsubscription.html#monitoritems)***